# Why tflite model got slow speed in multi batch inference

Tags: c++, tensorflow-lite

I converted a tiny bert module to tflite and run the inference with the tensorflow lite c++ api.

When batch size=1, tensorflow lite performs average runtime 0.6ms, while tensorflow performs average runtime 1ms(with default threads num); when batch size=10, tensorflow lite performs average runtime 5ms, while tensorflow performs average runtime 3ms.

It seems tensorflow lite did nothing on multi thread speed up, as i tried to apply SetNumThreads(4).

And SetNumThreads(4) and SetNumThreads(1) performs same runtime, though cpu usage changed from 100% to 200%.

I am wondering is this a normal performance for tflite in the X86 desktop?

Here is the part of my custom tflite c++ code

```
class Session {
public:
Session() {
  model_ = NULL;
  interpreter_ = NULL;
}

bool Open(const std::string &saved_model) {
model_ = tflite::FlatBufferModel::BuildFromFile(saved_model.c_str());
if (!model_) {
  return false;
}

tflite::InterpreterBuilder(*model_.get(), resolver_)(&interpreter_);

if (!interpreter_) {
  return false;
}
interpreter_->SetNumThreads(4);
return true;
}

bool Run(std::vector<int> &dims, int32_t *tok_id, int32_t *msk_id, int32_t *seg_id, float *output) const {
 int tok_index = interpreter_->inputs()[2];
 int msk_index = interpreter_->inputs()[1];
 int seg_index = interpreter_->inputs()[0];
 interpreter_->ResizeInputTensor(tok_index, dims);
 interpreter_->ResizeInputTensor(msk_index, dims);
 interpreter_->ResizeInputTensor(seg_index, dims);

 if(interpreter_->AllocateTensors() != kTfLiteOk) //remove AllocateTensors() did not change the runtime
     return false;
 int32_t bytes = dims[0] * dims[1] * sizeof(int32_t);
 int32_t* tok_tensor = interpreter_->typed_tensor<int32_t>(tok_index);
 memcpy(tok_tensor, tok_id, bytes);
 int32_t* msk_tensor = interpreter_->typed_tensor<int32_t>(msk_index);
 memcpy(msk_tensor, msk_id, bytes);
 int32_t* seg_tensor = interpreter_->typed_tensor<int32_t>(seg_index);
 memcpy(seg_tensor, seg_id, bytes);
 if(interpreter_->Invoke() != kTfLiteOk)
     return false;
 bytes = dims[0] * sizeof(float);
 float* result = interpreter_->typed_output_tensor<float>(0);
 memcpy(output, result, bytes);
 return true;
}

private:
std::unique_ptr<tflite::FlatBufferModel> model_;
std::unique_ptr<tflite::Interpreter> interpreter_;
tflite::ops::builtin::BuiltinOpResolver resolver_;
};
```

Comment: What do you mean by slow? We are talking about m i l l i s e c o n d s after all...

Comment: compare to the tensorflow c api, tflite is slower.....

Answer (score 2):

A few things:

- TensorFlow Lite is optimized for mobile deployment, which in practice typically means ARM-based devices. While we are actively working on improvements to x86 performance for TFLite, inference latency improvements may not be as consistent as they are on ARM CPUs.
- TensorFlow Lite is optimized for mobile-sized workloads, and may not be as optimized for larger batch sizes or multi-threading as standard TensorFlow.

If you're using a floating point model, the recently announced XNNPACK backend should provide some improvements for larger batch sizes and x86 devices. See also the [blog post](https://blog.tensorflow.org/2020/07/accelerating-tensorflow-lite-xnnpack-integration.html) announcing support in TF 2.3 and the latest nightly builds. For now, you'll have to opt-in at build time, but we hope to enable this backend by default for more devices and models in the near future.